# ES8 using arrow function with async and await

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch-api, arrow-functions, ecmascript-2017

I'm currently learning how to use ES8's fetch, async and await I currently have this code that works:

```
const url = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random";

async function tellJoke() {
  let data = await (await fetch(url)).json();
  return data.value.joke;
}

tellJoke().then(data => console.log(data));
```

Console:

```
"Chuck Norris can dereference NULL."
```

but I found a snippet using an arrow function, the problem is that I don't know how to return my value the way I'm doing it in my current example.

SNIPPET:

```
const fetchAsync = async () => 
await (await fetch(url)).json()
```

If this is not a best practice let me know, also any further reading is welcomed.

Comment: The best practise is to only use arrow functions when you need them. Just go with your working code :-)

Comment: Btw, `async`/`await` is part of ES8 not ES7

Comment: @Bergi that is true, forgot to check MDN and every example that I found mentioned ES7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can again use the same approach that you used to shorten the usual

```
async function tellJoke() {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let data = await response.json();
  return data.value.joke;
}
```

to your implementation. As a one-liner it can look like this:

```
const tellJoke = async () => (await (await fetch(url)).json()).value.joke;
```

Comment: Ok I understand now, by the way, i guess that doing


`let data = await response.json().value.joke;
  return data;`

Looks better than

`let data = await response.json();
  return data.value.joke;`

Can I know your opinion about it?

Comment: My personal opinion is not to introduce another variable only for returning it - `return` from a function named `tellJoke` is descriptive enough already. In any case, your first snippet doesn't work, you need parenthesis around the `await` expression.

Answer (score 3):

Use as same in the function. If you have no body expression in your code (witout `{}`), it will return the result of the statement. In this case the result of `await (await fetch(url)).json().value.joke`.

```
const fetchAsync = async () => (await (await fetch(url)).json()).value.joke;
```

or with multi line body. With body expression `{}` you need explicitly return as in simple function.

```
const fetchAsync = async () => {
   const result = await fetch(url);
   const data = await result.json();
   return data.value.joke;
}
```

Comment: `.json().value.joke` ... I think you need some ()  `(await (await fetch(url)).json()).value.joke;`

Comment: where I showed - I **think** ... I should probably check before speaking :p

Comment: yes, your code is wrong, because it will try to access `json().value.joke` ... but json() returns a promise, which doesn't have a `value` property, and it certainly wouldn't be the value of the json anyway